# Am I reading this respirometer correctly?

Tags: homework, experiment

I want to double check that I'm reading these respirometer vials correctly. The volume O2 of the following vials should be:

Squirrels in Torpor:

E1: 0.4 E2: 5.0 E3: 0.3 E4: 5.1 E5: 0.4 E6: 0

Squirrles at Stable body temperature in rewarming phase:

E1: 90.3 E2: 85.1 E3: 85.3 E4: 90.4 E5: 90 E6: 0

Right? Image below

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! This question seems like it might be a better fit for [MedicalSciences.SE], but please do **not** crosspost, instead request migration (or delete from this site and repost). Please note that both this site and that one expect  you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). For more details on how to use this site please take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask]. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, you're misreading the scale several times. The scale divisions indicate "tenth of ten" = one, while you sometimes misread them as "tenth of one" = 0.1.

For example:
E2 is correct as 5.0
E1 is just one mark less and should be 4.0 instead of 0.4.

(Remark: I don't know, whether to read the scale at the right or left side of the green part - I trust you using the right side)